# Feasibility to take over a JavaMe Project by Coders who have no experience in JavaMe

Tags: java, mobile

As the original JavaMe team will leave to do other items. 
The JavaMe project will be taken over by some guys knowing nothing about JavaMe.

Transition period: One month

About this JavaMe project:

1. about 35000 lines of code (more than 180 java file, SourceCode is 8.5KB in total)
2. using the Polish, Proguard
3. document: The JavaMe project itself have no document. No UML map.

Difficulties I guess:

1. familiar with the JavaMe, this should be okay
2. In order to do the further development. We need to Read the sourceCode ----  It's not easy to read 35,000 lines of code  having not enough comment
3. Adaptation work for more than 100 phone

These are the questions, thank you!

1. In the case of our guys have no experience in JavaMe, Is one month too hasty?
2. In order to take the job in time .  What we should ask the original JavaMe team to do .
3. Considering we hava no experience in JavaMe. The complication  we taking  the Adaptation work without the original JavaMe team?
4. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Stuff like this is quite common.  See the software quality triangle.  Of course the new guys will not write as good of code as the more experienced devs who also wrote and understand the system.  Ever heard a dev cuss up and down about how sorry ex-coderY's code is?  Often, this is due to missing documentation, lack of understanding, its harder to read code than write it...Unfortunately, that is the reality and the choice is often to take it for what it is or find a new job.

Comment: 3.5 million lines of code don't fit into 8500 bytes of storage, and neither sounds like 180 Java files (unless your files average about twenty thousand lines each, in which case you're doomed).  Some of your sizes are off, and it's impossible to tell which ones.

Comment: Another issue:  what is involved in taking over the project?  Will there be a lot of changes early on?

Comment: @David Thornley  Sorry. It's 35000 lines in fact -__-|||

Answer (score 1):

From your question it's hard to understand the size of the project. 3.5 million lines or 180 java files? 180 files is pretty small, 3.5 million lines is HUGE. Big difference.

Lack of documentation is not good. It likely means the code lacks 100%-defined structure, too. 
As new guys assume ownership, they'll start re-writing pieces. Thats not too bad, cause then they'll understand that new code, and it'll likely be more compact and work faster.

So you have 2 types of code right now: the code that is gonna get re-written and code that won't. You need some docs for both.

Ask your existing team which parts they would re-write, and why, if they had a chance, and have them answer you by email. This way you'll get some docs in place.

After that, ask them to write up a bit about patterns / naming conventions used in the other parts of the code (this is the code that is staying). UML maps are not terribly useful anyways, but if new guys will know that "whenever we call a class Manager it does X Y and Z and talks to Controller and Presenter", for example, it'll help.

Have the old guys give a 2-hour lecture about how J2ME works. After that, throw new guys into implementing a new feature / fixing a bug, with old guys shadowing.

If your new guys are decent engineers with Java experience, 1 month should be sufficient. The bigger worry is not the new technology but the size of code base.

as far as 100 different phone situation, it's pretty bad. If the old guys did any work in that regard, have them document what they seen, how are phones different from each other, what to watch out for etc.

Good luck!

Comment: THX!         And It's 35000 lines in fact -__-|||

Answer (score 1):

I would consider adding Javadoc step to the build process.  Output can go to a broweable directory. Get the outgoing team to document at least the most important classes.  (Especially those that will be kept.)  Javadoc for only the Public members would be appropriate.  This may be a good time to introduce some coding and documentation standards.

Add //TODO and //FIXME tags to the code if they aren't there would also help.  Getting the new team working on them with the help of the old team may help them get into the code.

I would want to have at least one developer/mentor who knows JavaME on the new team.  Getting the old team to spend some time pair programming with the new team may help get then started.  You may also want some team presentations on the MicroME, the Project, and the how the code was organized.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the quality of the previous code but you have two options. Either to write it again from scratch or enter the existing code.
I think that your developers will need at least 6 months to understand what has been made before and why. Another 6 months to code new and advanced features inside and existing code. Good luck because I did the same job and needed not one but 3 years with a large team to clean all the mess made by previous teams !!